# Store Record from Container Form Into Subforms Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

## A Little Background

My database has information about countries, languages, and territories; in the form I am having an issue with, I can input information about languages spoken into a country.

The following is a picture of the form, and subform I have at work in my database:

[image]

The subform that we see is a form with a country carousel at the top, and within it is a table with both language, and country information.

There is a `TerritoryID` identifier that sits in the parent form, that is relevant, necessary information for the tables at work.

I have the code to access it, using the `[Forms]![frmInput]!...` methodology.

## My Question

Is there some kind of "New Record" functionality in VBA, so that every time I **add a new record** by clicking the new dropdown box, that that new language can **carry with it** the in situ TerritoryID sitting in the parent form?

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the forms on the CountryID, it should automatically insert the CountryID in the new record.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you could use the method in the subform

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
   'left hand site the foreign key and Right hand site map to parent id
    Me!TerritoryID = [Forms]![frmInput]!...TerritoryID  
End Sub
```

Another VBA way to refer to parent form field:

```
Me!TerritoryID = Me.Parent!TerritoryID
```

Another solution is just to use the properties in the subform. Just use *Link Child Fields* and *Link Master Fields* and fill tit with the two Key fileds from parent and child.

A little bit old, but still valid with newer versions of Access is this link:
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/subforms/refresh.php